# Flutter GridView.count is not displaying all items

Tags: flutter, gridview

I'm trying to display the data using `GridView.count` but it is not displaying all items. here is my code

```
class CategoriesBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoriesBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategoriesBodyState createState() => _CategoriesBodyState();
}

class _CategoriesBodyState extends State<CategoriesBody> {
  
  Widget header() {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Container(
              color: appThemeColor,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            customText(context, "Available", 25.0,
                                FontWeight.w600, Colors.white),
                            customText(context, "Categories", 35.0,
                                FontWeight.w600, Colors.white),
                          ]))))),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: objResult == ""
                ? Column(
                    children: [
                      header(),
                      showCircularLoader(context),
                    ],
                  )
                : objResult == "not connected"
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          header(),
                          SizedBox30(),
                          noInternetConnection(context)
                        ],
                      )
                    : apiError == "Server down"
                        ? Column(
                            children: [
                              header(),
                              SizedBox30(),
                              serverError(context),
                            ],
                          )
                        : Center(
                            child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                header(),
                                
                                //list of all categries
                                SizedBox(
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        0.97,
                                    child: GridView.count(
                                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                        children: List.generate(category.length,
                                            (index) {
                                          return InkWell(
                                              child: customCategoryContainer(
                                                  context,
                                                  "assets/img/cat2.jpg",
                                                  category.length != 0
                                                      ? category[index].title
                                                      : "",
                                                  18.0,
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                          .size
                                                          .height *
                                                      0.18,
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                          .size
                                                          .height *
                                                      0.18));
                                        }))),
                               
                              ]))));
  }
}
```

api response count is 12, but its displaying 10 items. please help where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The items are probably there but larger than the screen height. And because you have a `SingleChildScrollView` and it's a scrollable widget, then the Grid is not scrollable, and the Grid and header are taking in total the full height of the screen and not more than that, so the `SingleChildScrollView` is also not scrollable.

One solution I can think of is to disable the scroll for the `SingleChildScrollView` widget and force scroll always for the Grid like so:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysisc(),
  //...
  child: Column(
    children: [
      //...
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height                                        * 0.97,
        child: GridView.count(
           physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           //...
        )
      ),
    ]
  ),

)
```

This will make the header fixed, and the grid scrollable within the screen height it occupies.

Comment: i tried this but it is not working, i change the ```height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height```  to ```height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height  *0.7```. it is displaying the left items.

Answer (score 0):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysisc(),
  //...
  child: Column(
    children: [
      //...
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
           physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           //...
        )
      ),
    ]
  ),

)
```

Comment: ```RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#63419 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT``` ERROR

Answer (score 0):

If this error happens to someone then set the height of `SizedBox` of `GridView.count` instead giving it to full screen height, this solve the issue.